# Pattern for egrep

Tags: regex, grep

I have a giant log file which among other things talks about run times. That's the information I want to extract. The log has lines that look like this:

```
Info: Executed check 'data_existence', result 'pass', took 0 s.
Info: Executed check 'message', result 'pass', took 20 s.
Info: Executed check 'blu', result 'pass', took 2 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'bla', result 'pass', took 2.5 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'foo', result 'pass', took 3.4 hours.
Info: Executed check 'bar', result 'pass', took 2.7 days.
```

I want to extract all lines that say 'Info ... took' (there is tons of other stuff in between) but to reduce clutter I want to skip lines that refer only to seconds.

So I wrote:

```
egrep 'Info: .*took\s*\d*\s*[mhd]' LOGs/my.log
```

Surprisingly (to me) it did not work (it came back blank). Although the checker at https://regex101.com/ said my pattern was finding something.

What's missing?

Thanks,
Gert

@John1024

```
sc-xterm-26:~> cat test
Info: Executed check 'data_existence', result 'pass', took 0 s.
Info: Executed check 'message', result 'pass', took 20 s.
Info: Executed check 'blu', result 'pass', took 2 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'blu', result 'pass', took 12 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'bla', result 'pass', took 2.5 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'foo', result 'pass', took 3.4 hours.
Info: Executed check 'bar', result 'pass', took 2.7 days.
sc-xterm-26:~>
sc-xterm-26:~>
sc-xterm-26:~> uname -a
Linux sc-xterm-26 3.0.52 #2 SMP Thu Dec 6 02:40:34 PST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sc-xterm-26:~> grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR     PURPOSE.

sc-xterm-26:~> grep -E 'Info: .*took\s*[0-9.]*\s*[mhd]' test
sc-xterm-26:~>
sc-xterm-26:~> grep -E 'Info: .*took\s*[[:digit:].]*\s*[mhd]' test
sc-xterm-26:~>
```

@All

I put the query into a TCL script and it works fine. No longer need a grep based solution. Best, Gert.

Comment: your regex doesn't seem to work in regex101

Comment: Never trust an online regexp checker. All command line tools have their own regexp flavors, delimiters, caveats, etc. - the online checkers are practically useless.  Very few tools will understand `\d` to mean a digit and almost as few will understand `\s` to mean a space.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` does not recognize `\d`.  Try:

```
$ grep -E 'Info:.*took\s*[0-9.]*\s*[mhd]' logfile
Info: Executed check 'bla', result 'pass', took 2.5 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'foo', result 'pass', took 3.4 hours.
Info: Executed check 'bar', result 'pass', took 2.7 days.
```

Or, better yet:

```
$ grep -E 'Info:.*took\s*[[:digit:].]*\s*[mhd]' logfile
Info: Executed check 'bla', result 'pass', took 2.5 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'foo', result 'pass', took 3.4 hours.
Info: Executed check 'bar', result 'pass', took 2.7 days.
```

Notes:

1. `egrep` is deprecated.  Use `grep -E` instead.
2. `grep` is supposed to support POSIX regular expressions.  `\s` is a GNU extension and may not be portable.  `\d` is not supported.
3. `[:digit:]` is unicode-safe which makes it a better choice than `0-9`.
4. To match floating point numbers, one must allow a decimal point in addition to digits.  Note that, outside of `[...]`, the period `.` is a wildcard.  Inside `[...]`, by contrast, it only matches a period.

#### More portable version

For greps that do not support `\s`, try:

```
$ grep -E 'Info:.*took[[:space:]]*[[:digit:].]*[[:space:]]*[mhd]' logfile
Info: Executed check 'bla', result 'pass', took 2.5 minutes.
Info: Executed check 'foo', result 'pass', took 3.4 hours.
Info: Executed check 'bar', result 'pass', took 2.7 days.
```

Comment: I tried both. They did not work. (grep comes back blank) The [mhd] seems to be the problem. When I cut it out grep returns the proper lines (with seconds included though). Gert

Comment: @GertGottschalk Since they worked fine for me, please provide more details.  What OS are you using?  What version of `grep`?  Also, while you may be surprised how often this happens: do the data files that you are testing on differ in _any_ way from the sample data  shown in the question?

Comment: @GertGottschalk Thanks for the update.  I just copied-and-pasted your new test file and your commands from the updated question and they again work fine for me.  This leads me to suspect that the original file has some special character that is lost when copying to SO.  Please try: `grep -E 'Info:.*took[[:space:]]*[[:digit:].]*[[:space:]]*[mhd]' logfile` and if that doesn't work, feed a problematic line or two of the log file to `-od -c` and let's see what characters are really in it.

Comment: @GertGottschalk you keep puting a blank char after `Info:` in the regexp you are using, unlike the regexp John is suggesting so what you are doing will fail if there's a tab character instead of a blank after `Info:`. Just try what John suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regex : `(Info: .*took\s*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*\s*(minutes|hours|days).)`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nP2tS0/2)

Comment: PS:I see John1024's answer better. Keeping this just for demo purpose.

Comment: The given line fails when using 'grep -E'. (Remember this is on a command line prompt. The shell might not like certain things. In the above case the shell said 'Badly placed ()'s.'

Comment: I tested using [this](http://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp) and it seems to work.

Comment: @GertGottschalk The shell won't see any part of that regexp if you quote it properly: `grep -E '(Info: .*took\s*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*\s*(minutes|hours|days).)' file`. I'm not saying you should use it as it has some issues (see @John1024's answer instead) but it won't produce the error message you saw if it's quoted correctly.